# EF Core exclude certain property in query, many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

How do I query certain properties only in a database that has many-to-many relationship?

So I have a book that can have multiple authors

```cs
public class Book
{
    public Book()
    {
        Authors = new List<BookAuthor>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<BookAuthor> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

Joined table for Book and Author

```cs
public class BookAuthor
{
    public string BookId{ get; set; }
    public string AuthorId{ get; set; }

    public Book book{ get; set; }
    public Author author{ get; set; }
}
```

Finally, the Author can write multiple books

```cs
public class Author
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<BookAuthor> books { get; set; }

}
```

Now, when I want to query a book and return the book id and description NOT the List of authors of that book

```
return await _context.Book.Select(x => new Book
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Description = x.Description,        
        }).ToListAsync();
```

When I do this I got

```json
{
    "id": "BOOK123",
    "description": "Stack Overflow 101",
    "Authors": []
}
```

I want to exclude the property Author from Book class in my query's return. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can create a `BookDto` class which will not have this property and create it in your `Select` call.

Comment: Can you give more pointers? Sorry, I am pretty new to this.

Comment: You need to declare a new class looking similar to your `Books` one without `Authors` property and constructor. After that you need to change `_context.Book.Select(x => new Book` to `_context.Book.Select(x => new BookDto` where `BookDto` is the na,e of your class.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a DTO object for Book:

```
public class BookDto
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and then call:

```
return await _context.Book.Select(x => new BookDto
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Description = x.Description,        
}).ToListAsync();
```

More advanced approach would be to use Automapper (https://automapper.org/) and create a mapping profile between your Book and BookDto:

```
public class BookProfile : Profile
    {
        public BookProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Book, BookDto>();
        }
    }
```

and then you could retrieve your BookDtos like this:

```
return await _context.Book
.ProjectTo<BookDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
.ToListAsync();
```

where _mapper is of type IMapper.

Comment: cool. but let say inside my DTO I have more than just id and description (like few more property and another object). Is there a way to query them all like using include(), instead of mapping 1 by 1 (Id = x.Id etc) thanks

Comment: You need post a code sample, but I don't think that you can achieve it without explicit mapping.